# Why aren't these types compatible?

Tags: c++, dll, wrapper, labview

I'm very new to C++. I am trying to get a C++ DLL to import correctly into LabVIEW, so in order to do that, I'm trying to make my own wrapper around that DLL. Here's a [relevant article](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019L0sSAE&l=en-US) about why I need to.

Part of this process involves defining my own types so I can convert LabVIEW data into a format compatible with C++. Let me give an example. Note that I don't have the original DLL's source code, just the header file.

One of the functions I'm trying to call has this prototype:

```
BirdBDS2API int DLL_CALLING bds2dll_setStdConfig(BDS2DLL_HANDLE p_bds2dll_handle, BDS2_StdConfig* p_stdCfg, BDS2_Fundamental* p_funds, BDS2_MultiState* p_states);
```

The parameters I'm trying to redefine are defined like this in the header file:

```
typedef struct _DLLStdConfig_t
{
    unsigned int numFunds;          // The number of fundamentals.
    unsigned int pulseTriggerDelay; // Pulse mode trigger delay in microSeconds.
    unsigned int displayUpdateRate; // Data production rate.
    unsigned int numStates;         // The number of states.
    unsigned int pulsePeriod;       // Pulse period in usecs. 
    unsigned int numMeasReq;        //  number of measurements required. 
} BDS2_StdConfig;

typedef struct _DLLFundamental_t
{
    unsigned int  freqHz;                       // Fundamental frequency (in Hz).
    unsigned int  harmSel[BDS2_MAX_HARMONICS];  // Harmonic selection.
    unsigned int  intermodFund2;                // F2 fundamental for intermod.
    unsigned int  intermodSel;                  // as defined BDS2_eIntermodSel
    unsigned int  detFilter;                    // as defined in BDS2_eDetFilter.
    float         vNoiseLevel;                  // Voltage Noise floor level. volts.
    float         iNoiseLevel;                  // Current Noise floor level. amps.
    unsigned int  viTracking;                   // as defined in BDS2_eVITracking.
    unsigned int  measMode;                     // as defined in BDS2_eMeasMode.
    unsigned int  trackingMode;                 // as defined in BDS2_eTrackingMode.
    unsigned int  stateFreqHz[BDS2_MAX_STATES]; // state measurement freq..

} BDS2_Fundamental;

typedef struct _DLLMultiStateConfig_t
{
    unsigned int trkStateDelay;             // Std tracking state delay.
    unsigned int trkStateDuration;          // Std tracking state duration.
    unsigned int trkStateNumberOfFrames;    // Std tracking state number of frames.
} BDS2_MultiState;
```

LabVIEW was interpreting these incorrectly when importing the DLL, so I tried to redefine them like so using LabVIEW's tools:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int numFunds;
    unsigned int pulseTriggerDelay;
    unsigned int displayUpdateRate;
    unsigned int numStates;
    unsigned int pulsePeriod;
    unsigned int numMeasReq;
} TD1;

typedef struct {
    int dimSize;
    unsigned int harmSel[4];
} TD3;
typedef TD3** TD3Hdl;

typedef struct {
    int dimSize;
    unsigned int stateFreqHz[4];
} TD4;
typedef TD4** TD4Hdl;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int freqHz;
    TD3Hdl harmSel;
    unsigned int intermodFund2;
    unsigned int intermodSel;
    unsigned int detFilter;
    float vNoiseLevel;
    float iNoiseLevel;
    unsigned int viTracking;
    unsigned int measMode;
    unsigned int trackingMode;
    TD4Hdl stateFreqHz;
} TD2;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int trkStateDelay;
    unsigned int trkStateDuration;
    unsigned int trkStateNumberOfFrames;
} TD5;
```

I then have my own function definition of:

```
int DLL_CALLING bds2wrap_setStdConfig(BDS2DLL_HANDLE p_bds2dll_handle, TD1* p_stdCfg, TD2* p_funds, TD5* p_states)
{
    int out = bds2dll_setStdConfig(p_bds2dll_handle, p_stdCfg, p_funds, p_states);
    return out;
}
```

However, I'm getting the error `"Argument of type TD1 *" is incompatible with parameter of type "BDS2_StdConfig *"`. I get a similar error for each of the parameters I tried to redefine. As I said, I'm new to C++, so I'm unsure if this is an error where I'm missing something that would be obvious to someone more experienced, or something that's specific to the LabVIEW tools I'm trying to use. As far as I can tell, the types I'm redefining are equivalent to their originals. The array sizes I used match the variable declarations in the original header file.

Comment: It must be the same class/struct definition, not just same member variable types and names.

Comment: You probably just need to cast from your type to the required type. Like this (for instance) `(BDS2_StdConfig*)p_stdCfg`

Comment: ... or solve the real problem

Comment: it is not clear why you think you need to redefine thsoe types (also not clear after reading the labview link). No matter if labview has problems to interpret them, in your c++ code you can simply use the original types, no?

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need the `typedef` before `struct`.  You also don't need `struct` when declaring variables or function parameters.

Comment: @Justin so does that mean this is just impossible for me to do? Or is there a way for me to coerce it/ a different way to declare it?